# Having several problems creating a chatpage in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Im having several problems working on a chatpage, i'm trying to make the chatbox the size of the text plus a small space but im having problems doing that, also the chatbox is overlapping outside the screen and i want the date stamp to be directly under every chatbox but im also engaging in problems doing that. Here is the code and below is a picture of my current situation. ill really appreciate any help

```
 def send_message(self, _):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        message = self.messagetextinput.text
        if len(message) > 0:
            database.child("messages").child(app.localId).update({self.localId: message})
            self.chatbubble = Button( background_color = [0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0], background_normal = "",
                                      pos_hint= {"center_x": 1}, color = (1, 1, 1, 1), size_hint_y = None, halign = "left", valign = "middle", text_size = (290, 40), font_name = "fonts/Qanelas-Regular.otf" )
            self.now = datetime.now()
            self.dt_string = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:")
            self.timestamp = Label(text = str(self.dt_string),  pos_hint= {"center_x": 1}, color = (0, 0, 0, 1), size_hint = (.8, .1))

            self.chatbubble.text = self.messagetextinput.text
            self.ids.chatlayout.add_widget(self.chatbubble)
            self.add_widget(self.timestamp)
            self.ids.scrollview.scroll_to(self.chatbubble)
            self.messagetextinput.text = ""


            Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 0.1)

 def focus_text_input(self, _):
        self.messagetextinput.focus = True
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a bunch of if statements regarding the length of text, depending on the length of text the size of the chat bubble would adjust and the reason why the time wasn't showing under the chatbox was because i was mistakenly adding it into the scrollview and not the boxlayout that the chatbox is in